# How to turn hex code into x86 instructions

Tags: linux, bash, assembly, x86-64, objdump

I'm trying to make a script or program that will take given bytes (given in hexadecimal), and convert them into a x86 instructions (For example c3 -> retq)

I've tried doing it by calling `gcc -c` on an assembly file just containing

```
retq
retq
```

and then using a script to insert bytes where it says "c3 c3", then using `objdump -d` to see what it says now. But it seems that it messes up the format of the file unless I only pass an instruction of the same size as the original instruction bytes.

I'm running it on a Raspbian Pi (A linux based operating system) using SSH, BASH terminal. I'm using BASH shell scripts and python, as well as the tools listed here, and gdb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disassemble flat binary file: `objdump -D -b binary -m i386 foo.bin`. Or create an object file using `.byte` directives from assembly source, e.g. put `.byte 0xc3` into `foo.s` then `gcc -c foo.s` then `objdump -d foo.o`

Comment: If you literally have a hexdump, not a binary, you could also hex-"undump" back to a binary you can disassemble.  `xxd -r` does that, and it may be easier than massaging it into a comma-separated list of bytes as an operand to a `.byte` directive.

Comment: Thank you so much! Both of those worked extremely well =]